# show Notification stars (*) in header when a file changes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, notifications, inotifypropertychanged

i have a project with text file editor , but i need to implement feature where in there changes in file it will show stars `(*)` i the header next to the file title , so it notified the user there changes in the file ... same in  visual studio when you edit the xaml file or edit the code you get `(*)` that file is modified.

Is there some method which I can add to do the feature when a file is modified on the disc?

Comment: if you detect an unsaved change, you can set a `dirty` flag. Whether or not this is true, show or hide the `*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MVVM, you can use a property that depends on another one.

When `IsDirty` flag  is changed, there is a notification on `DecoratedTitle`

```
class Document : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool isDirty;
    public bool IsDirty
    {
        get { return isDirty; }
        set
        {
            isDirty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged("DecoratedTitle");
        }
    }
    private String title;
    public String Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set
        {
            title = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public String DecoratedTitle
    {
        get { return title + (isDirty ? " (*)" : ""); }

    }
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Then you can bind the window to the DecoratedTitle :

```
<Window Title="{Binding DecoratedTitle}"  >
```

Regards